# Devexpress: repositoryitemtextedit и маска

Tags: c#, devexpress

Есть у меня GridControl от Devexpress. Для одного column  этого грида задан columnedit : repositoryitemtextedit . Таблица содержит типы документов и номера. Среди типов есть свидетельство о рождении. Свидетельство о рождении имеет следующий формат:

> - Серия: римские буквы (в латинском регистре),  две буквы кириллицей
> - Номер: шесть цифр
> - Например: XXXVЦФ123456

Пробую задать маску следующим образом

```
repForDocNum.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Regular;                    
repForDocNum.Mask.EditMask = "(^[XMVIL]+)\\s([А-Я]{2})\\s($\\d{6})";
```

Работать работает, но коряво - при входе в ячейку таблицы вместо красивых знаков нижнего подчёркивания, показывается часть этого регулярного выражения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как сделать грамотно маску для ввода, состоящую из 3-х частей, разделённых пробелом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общих чертах, регулярное выражение которое вы используете как маску, верное. Необходимо исправить несколько моментов, чтобы оно заработало как следует.

1. Не нужно использовать символы начала и конца текста (^ и $).
2. Чтобы было удобно вводить метасимволы (например \s - пробел), перед строкой лучше ввести символ @. Тогда не нужно будет путаться с экранированием обратных слешей.
3. Скобки в основном применяются для группировки логических частей выражения, а не для выделения фрагментов.

По идее, это все. Вот такое выражение должно получиться после исправлений:

```
repForDocNum.Mask.EditMask = @"[XMVIL]+[А-Я]{2}\d{6}";
```

Обратите внимание на примеры регулярных выражений в официальной документации DevExpress: [Mask Type: Extended Regular Expressions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1501). Они покрывают большинство популярных задач, в том числе и эту.

Comment: Вот такой текст отображается при помещении фокуса в пустую ячейку:
_s__s______
Лучше, но ещё бы символ s упрятать

Comment: Видимо я неверно истолковал документацию, и \s это не пробел а просто вставка символа s. Смотрите последнюю строчку в большой таблице из документации. А так как у вас в ожидаемом результате нет пробелов, то и не нужно этот символ вставлять. И тогда выражение будет вот таким (я исправил в ответе тоже): `[XMVIL]+[А-Я]{2}\d{6}`.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, помогло